# Write GeoJson into a .geojson file with Python

Tags: python, geojson, file-formats

I want to write a geosjon object with the type `<class 'geojson.feature.Feature'>` into a .geosjon file. Therefore I tried to use

```
with open(test.geosjon, 'w') as outfile:
     geojson.dump(geosjon_geometries, outfile)
```

But i get the error `TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, tuple found`
I figured out that with this function a dict is needed to write it into a geosjon file. Is there another possibility to write a geojson feature in a file?

The function looks like:

```
def write_json(self, features):
    # feature is a shapely geometry feature
    geom_in_geojson = geojson.Feature(geometry=features, properties={})
    tmp_file = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix='.geojson')
    with open(tmp_file, 'w') as outfile:
        geojson.dump(geom_in_geojson, outfile)
    return tmp_file
```

The input is a shapely geometry, e.g. MultiLineString or LineString

Comment: Can you show the logic for the class?  I would recommend working with the json module.

Comment: I added the function to the question

Comment: I found the solution. It is working like this. The problem was the funktion `tempfile.mkstep()`. This returns a touple. So for the correct path to the temporary file it has to be used `tmp_file[1]`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To write a geojson object to a temporary file this function can be used:

```
import geojson
import tempfile

def write_json(self, features):
   # feature is a shapely geometry type
   geom_in_geojson = geojson.Feature(geometry=features, properties={})
   tmp_file = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix='.geojson')
   with open(tmp_file[1], 'w') as outfile:
      geojson.dump(geom_in_geojson, outfile)
   return tmp_file[1]
```

Comment: can you break it down, I want to store geopandas GoDataFrame as temporary file, I changed the code as: import geojson
import tempfile

def write_json(self, features):
    geom_in_geojson = geojson.Feature(geometry=df_new['geometry'], properties={df_new['pod']})
    tmp_file = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix='.geojson')
    print(tmp_file[1])
    with open(tmp_file[1], 'w') as outfile:
        print(tmp_file[1])
        geojson.dump(geom_in_geojson, outfile)
    return tmp_file[1] ## but it did not worked @Martin

Comment: what are self, features in def write_json(self, features):

Answer (score 29):

Dumping a list of features directly does not create a valid GeoJSON file.

To create valid GeoJSON:

1. Create a list of features (where each feature has geometry and optional properties)
2. Create a collection (e.g. FeatureCollection) with those features
3. Dump the collection to a file.

e.g.

```
from geojson import Point, Feature, FeatureCollection, dump

point = Point((-115.81, 37.24))

features = []
features.append(Feature(geometry=point, properties={"country": "Spain"}))

# add more features...
# features.append(...)

feature_collection = FeatureCollection(features)

with open('myfile.geojson', 'w') as f:
   dump(feature_collection, f)
```

Output:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-115.81, 37.24]
        },
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "country": "Spain"
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: thank for a good answer. GeoJson can accept a shapely geometry object.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing that geom is a shapely geometry object, you can use

```
from shapely.geometry import mapping
import json

geojson = json.dumps(mapping(geom))
```